# Prevent iOS overscroll/bounce effect on body AND scrollable child container?

Tags: jquery, ios, web-applications, scroll

I have a responsive webapp which contains a scrollable body (no scroll container) and a modal (dialog). When the modal is hidden, I need the body to **stay scrollable** to make the URL bar hid automatically when I scroll down the page on mobile devices. As many others I want to "remove" the scroll from the body when the modal is displayed, **BUT** I still want to be able to scroll in the modal. So this i easly fixed by toggeling a noScroll class on the body which has overflow: hidden.

```
.noScroll { 
  overflow: hidden; //does not remove overscroll 
}
```

**BUT** this does not remove the scroll entirely. The iOS overscroll/bouncing effect is still happening on the body. I tried setting position: fixed in the noScroll class as well, but i did not work 100%.

```
.noScroll { 
  overflow: hidden; //does not remove overscroll 
  position: fixed; //does not work a 100% 
}
```

It is the same for this code (it works a little bit better than position: fixed):

```
$(document).on("touchmove", function (event) {
    if($(#modal).is('visible')
        event.preventDefault();
});

$('#modal').on("touchmove", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**The problem is** that the overscroll/bounce effect is still happening on the modal (the modal is displayed on the top of the page). It seems that I am able to trigger the "page scroll" through the modal even when the scroll is removed from the body or the document. When this happens it is not possible to scroll inside the modal. I then have to doble tap or tap it really hard to be able to scroll it again.

So finally, **my question:** Is it possible to all at once:

- have a scrollable body on default to make the url bar hid as I scroll down
- to remove "pgae scroll" when a **scrollable** modal is displayed
- Prevent overscroll in the modal
- keep the modal at the top

I am also satisfied with just an explanation of why this is happening.

**NOTE**: This works perfectly on android/chrome.

**EDIT** The main issue is that I have to double tap the modal, or tap it really hard before it is possible to scroll it again.